# Refactoring code out of the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, refactoring, helper

I have the following view code which displays events, along with headers informing the user if the following events occured today, yesterday, or in the past week.

It all works fine, but I would prefer to refactor it out of the view, I can't put it in a helper because it needs to maintain the variables state between loop iterations. Any idea how to tidy this up? thanks

```
<% displayed_week_already = false %>
<% displayed_yesterday_already = false %>
<% displayed_today_already = false %>

<% @events.each do |event| %>

  <%= event.title &>

  <% if (Time.now - 1.week) > event.created_at && !displayed_week_already %>
    <% displayed_week_already = true %>
    Events in past week
  <% elsif (Time.now - 1.day) > event.created_at && (Time.now - 2.day) < event.created_at && !displayed_yesterday_already %>
    <% displayed_yesterday_already = true %>
    Events yesterday
  <% elsif (Time.now - 1.day) < event.created_at && !displayed_today_already %>
    <% displayed_today_already = true %>
    Events in past day
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

---

Expected output would be:

**Events in past day**
John created a new artice
Dan commented on article 1
Sue deleted article 2

**Events yesterday**
Sue created a new article

**Events in past week**
Carol was promoted
Dan cerated a new article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do something like the following. I am leaving out the implemented methods defined on the model itself.

### existing view

```
<%= render "events", :title => "Events in past day",  :events => from_today(@events) %>
<%= render "events", :title => "Events yesterday",    :events => from_yesterday(@events) %>
<%= render "events", :title => "Events in past week", :events => from_this_week(@events) %>
```

### _events.html.erb

```
<% if events.present? %>
  <%= title %>
  <% events.each do |event| %>
    <%= event.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

### app/helpers/event_display_helper.rb

```
module EventDisplayHelper
  def from_today(events)
    events.select{|x| x.happened_today?}
  end

  def from_yesterday(events)
    events.select{|x| x.happened_yesterday?}
  end

  def from_this_week(events)
    events.select{|x| x.happened_this_week_before_yesterday?}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do this in the model, with named scopes (I'm assuming Rails 3 because that's what I know best). You'll need to define them yourself but they're pretty simple.

```
@last_week = @event.last_week
@yesterday = @event.yesterday
@today = @event.today
```

Then just iterate over each of the groups in your view. Should make it a lot cleaner and you won't need so much logic, as it's where it actually belongs.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I did consider this, but it makes pagination awkward, if not impossible.

Comment: Ok, what's the actual output you'd expect from this? Maybe we can come up with something else that works for you, and would make pagination easier.

Comment: Where would the pagination go in your example? I'd be inclined to suggest loading each block of events via Ajax, and paginating each block individually to support that.

Comment: Imagine 10 events per page, if there are 11 events on the first day, you will see "Events in past day" on page 1, and "Events yesterday" on page 2. It's just a time line with some headers added to add some context. It works exactly how i want it to now, it's just not an elegant solution

Comment: Well... in that case, I'm not sure there's any way to make it cleaner (not with my limited knowledge anyway). Hopefully someone else will chip in!